# È corretta la frase "oggi vorrei raccontarti una storia che è successa un'anno fa."?

Tags: grammar

Vorrei sapere se questa frase suona bene ed è grammaticamente corretta.
Non sono sicuro se devo usare il verbo "succedere" o preferire il verbo "accadere".

Grazie in anticipo:)

Comment: La tua frase è corretta per la grammatica. Dire se "suona bene" dipende dall'orecchio di chi ascolta (doppia c e doppia s in sequenza possono dar fastidio a qualcuno) :-) I due verbi sono sinonimi, ma in generale "accadere" è meno frequente nel parlato. Un terzo verbo sinonimo di questi è "capitare".

Comment: Hai un apostrofo di troppo. Comunque considera anche "Oggi vorrei raccontarti un fatto accaduto un anno fa".

Comment: @Benedetta Direi che potresti trasformare il tuo commento in una risposta :).

Comment: In realtà credo sia più corretto l'utilizzo del passato remoto (“oggi vorrei raccontarti una storia che successe/accadde un anno fa."), ma nel parlato è comune l'utilizzo del passato prossimo.

Comment: Sono d'accordo con Riccardo sul passato remoto, anche se la vera distinzione è se il fatto di un anno fa si concluse allora o continua ad avere effetto. Direi quindi, per esempio “...una storia che successe un anno fa: Gigi si mise un dito nel naso”, ma “...una storia che è successa un anno fa: Gigi e Titti, senza dire niente a nessuno, si sono sposati”.

Comment: @DenisNardin: procedo :)

Comment: La frase suona male perché le "storie" non accadono, né succedono. Il commento di VincenzoOliva è ottimo, aggiungo dei dati a sostegno, da [Ngram](https://goo.gl/izuwnj)

Answer (score 4):

Nella frase è presente un errore di grammatica relativo all'articolo indeterminativo. "Anno", infatti, è una parola maschile; l'articolo deve essere "un": «un anno fa».

Nell'uso del verbo, invece, la tua frase è corretta per la grammatica. Dire se "suona bene" dipende dall'orecchio di chi ascolta (a qualcuno, doppia ”c“ e doppia ”s“ in sequenza possono dar fastidio).

I due verbi sono sinonimi, ma in generale "accadere" è meno frequente nel parlato. Un terzo verbo sinonimo di questi è "capitare".

Comment: Aggiungerei il fatto dell'apostrofo, altrimenti non è vero che è corretta...

Comment: @DaG, grazie, ho fatto l'aggiunta.